# Accessing associated objects through a specific table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :saved_courses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :saved_courses

  has_many :course_completions
  has_many :courses, through: :course_completions

end
```

And its course counterpart:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :course_completions
  has_many :users, through: :course_completions

  has_many :saved_courses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :saved_courses

end
```

Based on these relationships, how do I get an array of all of the `courses` that a `@user` has saved?

As in, when I do `@user.courses`, I want it grab its saved courses, but not completed courses. I tried to do `@user.saved_courses.courses` but that doesn't seem like a valid operation. And `@user.saved_courses.to_a` simply returns an array of saved_courses, whereas I need to go a step further from there and grab the courses that those saved_course items represent.

**Bonus points:** I'm trying to do this in the shortest, most elegant way possible. For example, I don't want to manually iterate over `@user.saved_courses.to_a`, find the courses and push them into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two associations named the same thing isn't going to work. You're going to need to do something the effect of

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :saved_courses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :saved_course_courses, through: :saved_courses, source: :course

  has_many :course_completions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :course_completion_courses, through: :course_completions, source: :course
end
```

Note the use of :source, which tells `ActiveRecord` which class the has_many is referring to. Then when you're going through and want all of a user's courses, you would do: `user.saved_course_courses + user.course_completion_courses`

Comment: You beat me to it. Good answer.